# Combobox value not getting selected when form is dynamically loaded

Tags: extjs

I am making a form which is an edit screen. That means data has to be populated on load of the screen, I am using spring mvc controller to achieve this. All the textbox data getting loaded. But combobox is not selected. Do I need to do anything extra for combobox? Below is the piece of code used for getting data:

```
Ext.getCmp('ADD_ADDRESS_Panel').getForm().load({
       url: '/omsWeb/order/Addressload.htm?accountid=1223', 
       method: 'GET',
       failure: function(form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Load failed", action.result.errorMessage);
       }
```

Thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

For setting a combo box on form load, the combo box's store needs to be loaded first. After the store has loaded, load the form. It will work fine. If it doesn't then the work around would be something like this:

```
form.getForm().load({
   .. config.. 
   success : function(form, action){
    if(action.result){
      var data = action.result.data;
      var store = combo.getStore();
      store.each(function(record){
        if(record.data.id===data.id){
        cmp.setValue(record.data.id);
         return false;
        }
      });
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: @Praveen: Accept the answer. Helps other people having the same problem